# Android Studio : Can't build throw error version 1.5

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, overriding

Since I have updated my android studio to version 1.5, building project throws me an error while I add new fragment to it

```
  @Override
public void onAttach(Activity context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Error thrown on second line of the code ie.. `super.onAttach(context)`

Log is shown as `@overrride method does not override or implement method of a supertype`

Comment: there should be problem with your appcompat jar file...i think

Comment: I have not imported any files yet !!

Comment: It is an empty project with only fragment on it

Comment: @overrride method does not override or implement method of a supertype... look at this error it clearly shows that it is not getting the inbuilt library classes...

Comment: tell me what is your library version??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for deprecated library..

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    Activity a;

    if (context instanceof Activity){
        a=(Activity) context;
    }

}
```